# VHDL CLK = '1' vs rising_edge(CLK)

Tags: vhdl

I've been thinking what is the difference between CLK = '1' and rising_edge(CLK) in process.

The thing with process is that when a signal changed then the process is executed. So a change from 0 -> 1 happened once so it should trigger process only once. It will check the if statements which looks like :

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        sCounter <= sCounter \+ 1;
    end if;
end process;
process (clk)
begin
    if clk = '1' then
        sCounter <= sCouner \+ 1;
    end if;
end process;
```

So it should do it once on both if statements if signal is not 1 or rising then the output stays the same like in latch. In Simulation it shows the same.

So I don't get it why in synthesis it changes this CLK = '1' into latch that if CLK = 1 then instead of triggering the process once bit triggers multiple times which increments the counter more than one time ...

EDIT:

Maybe the title is the same, and questions sounds similar but the answer I've seen in one of the links didn't answer my question or rather made me more confused.

The simulation shows it works correct for both CLK = '1' and for rising_edge(CLK), so it made me think why it is like that and why synthesizing it made it work incorrect. Hence the process works different and It's hard to say why it works this way.

Comment: @thebusybee I've read it and I didn't understood the answers, didn't even know about this post and couldn't find more results, but it still didn't answer my questions, because the answers weren't that understandable for me because it went deeper into how process works or so.

Comment: Did anyone read the article referenced that was used to close this one?   As someone who worked on the register section of 1076.6 standard, all of the answers talk around the subject, but don't actually explain the what and why of the issue.    I guess I will try to post an answer to the old article and see if it takes or if it is just a waste of time.

Comment: The short answer is that many synthesis tools ignore sensitivity lists.   When doing this, they effectively replace the sensitivity list with all inputs to the process.   Hence, in your case, the sensitivity list constructed by the synthesis tool is `process (Clk, sCounter)`.   Hence, code without a rising_edge or 'event becomes a latch instead of a flipflop.   It is frustrating, but synthesis tools have based their patent portfolio on things like this, so there is no way to get them to change - it would be expensive and have very little return on investment.

Comment: @JimLewis Ah okey so the process is still the same (I mean the code) but the sensitive is changed. So looking at the code, First CLK triggers the process then because sCounter again was triggered and the CLK is still equal = 1 then the process again increments it ... Ehhhhhh it is so annoying when I think about it ... And the testbench to be honest doesn't help alot when I think about it right now. Because it showed my code worked for both CLK = 1 and for CLK rising in the same way.

Comment: Since the synthesis tool modifies the sensitivity list, the semantics of the synthesized gate logic does not match the RTL code.   There is nothing wrong with the testbench itself as in RTL sim they do indeed work the same and from a VHDL perspective that is correct.   Again it is just the synthesis that fouls things up.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not check for a rising or falling clock edge in a process, synthesis must implement the process without any flipflops. So when you check by "CLK=1", but CLK is equal to 0, then in simulation the counter holds its value. Synthesis wants to create the same storing behaviour, so it has to use a latch which is transparent at CLK=1 and stores at CLK=0. Synthesis will also give you a warning, that counter is read in the process, but not part of the sensitivity list. Synthesis will then add counter to the sensitivity list. If you then also add counter to the sensitivity list of your process, you will see that you have described a latch.

Comment: Technically if I have rising_edge(CLK) then when I check by CLK 0 -> 1 then process is triggered the counter should change when CLK is equal 0, 1 or 1->0 then it should change the counter. Of course when signal changes from 1 -> 0 it again triggers the process but it won't change the counter. With CLK = 1 it seems the same, if I have anything than CLK = 1 which is 0, 1->0 or 0->1 then it should update the counter. So both of them acts like latch. But here comes the question, what process sees ? usually it is triggered by 1 -> 0 or 0->1 so will it see "1" or "0" ? It should see the transist.

Comment: Hmmmm the process thing makes me thing though because it is proceeded once, so how CLK is able to see that CLK = 1 when process is triggered by 1-> 0 or 0->1 so it should see the transistion, and rising edge actually sees the transist because process is triggered by 1->0 so the clk sees 1-> 0 and not "0". hmmm logic errors from my side but don't know how to answer it to myself. But I still see them as both latches.

Comment: Please be aware of the difference between a latch and a flipflop. A latch is transparent during all the time its enable is active (here if CLK=1).

Comment: It doesnt have to. The given example will synthesise to a register in Quartus (and has done for many years - see link posted by @thebusybee ) because `sCounter ` is not in the sensitivity list. But in general, synthesis tools ignore sensitivity. There is no standard on logic synthesis, as a proposed standard was withdrawn.

Comment: @Jackob2001 While the 2nd example will produce a register in some synth tools, in simulation you have to deal with the fact that any transition to '1' will also bee seen as a "rising edge". This could be 'X' -> '1', 'U' -> '1' etc. This may not be desirable. The `rising_edge` function clears this up, only allowing a transition from '0' (or 'L') to '1' (or 'H').

Comment: @MatthiasSchweikart , but then the process doesn't make any sense. Because process by definition should only be triggered when the signal in sensitive list changes his state, when it changed only once it should trigger only once. So the process doesn't make any sense. So the sensitive doesn't make any sense in this case or rather why it is there.

Comment: @Tricky I don't get it that much, and I've read what thebusybee has provided. as if the process doesn't make any sense. It should proceed once as it was meant to do, but then synthezis just ignores it as if process doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: There are no specs for how tools are to implement logic from any code. Hence all tools can be different. Most ignore sensitivity lists. hence using `if clk = '1' then` will just produce a latch.

Comment: @Tricky Okey so why process are introduced in lessons about VHDL that are triggered by the change of the signal in this sensitivity lists. If it's not triggered by the change of the signal inside the brackets like process(Something), and if that something doesn't matter then how to analyze these process stuff. In tutorials it always says to follow it as a change from 0 to 1 or 0 to 1 or any change at all. I don't get it.

Comment: VHDL was originally intended as a simulation language. Triggering a process on a change is the mechanic of the language and well defined for how the language behaves. Later on synthesis tools arrived that could convert VHDL to logic.  There is no spec for how to convert VHDL to logic.

Comment: @Tricky Then is this a guess game when I use process ? Once it will be triggered by the change of the signal and once not. 
I've seen some examples how process works but then I see some Reset in that process so I have a latch because Reset = 1 ... and a Clock that is rising ... Like in simple example but there is only Reset = 1 so in fact it's latching. But okey, there are other examples like logic combination using only inputs like INPUT A and INPUT B inside of the process sensitive lists. 
To be honest I don't know how to understand this process then, or how to interpret or use it correct

Comment: Because the process will be interpreted by the language the same and the simulation will give something okey. I mean if I used CLK = 1 or CLK rising in simulation it should show the same as I understand but in synthezis and in reality not. So I don't understand how to use process at this moment to be honest or how to read it because in language I read it as something that is triggered by the change and once not ... even though I would read it as defined by many tutorials, so I don't know how to read it then.

Comment: @Tricky What do you think about it ?

Comment: All synth tools have user guides on what language templates they require to infer specific logic constructs (registers, RAM, muxes etc). I recommend you read the guide for the synthesis tool you are using.

Comment: @Tricky So I understand that in simulation it will always work the same the CLK = '1' and CLK rising, but synthesis will change it. And the synthesis works differently and I have to write it differently. Which is weird but ok.

Comment: Synthesis tools will adhere to IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 ((RTL) SYNTHESIS, withdrawn for lack of vendor participation) 6. Modeling hardware elements, 6.1 Edge-sensitive sequential logic. Where synthesis tools vary is availability of features restricted by device architecture and unique features like tri-state muxes4 and deep analysis allowing the use of while loops. Tools shouldn't mistake an inferred latch for a register (see 6.2 Level-sensitive sequential logic for the rules).